# Java exception error causing code to stop suddenly

Tags: java, exception, nosuchelementexception

I was working on a project for class and everything works fine until the code the professor gave us that will prompt the user to "doOver" the code if they choose to, it's coming out with this error and I'm frankly confused.

I tried changing the sc.nextLine to a .hasNextLine as I've seen in other posts, but it comes up with an error stating it needs to be a boolean and then says I can not use the next doOver.trim() code on a boolean.

```
final static String TITLE = "ISBN-13 Generator!";
final static String CONTINUE_PROMPT = "\nDo this again? [y/n] ";
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private static void process(Scanner sc, String args[]) {

    boolean numberChecker;
    String isbn;
    do {
        System.out.println("\nEnter the first 12 digits of an ISBN-13: ");
        isbn = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
        isbn = isbn.trim();
        numberChecker = true;
        int s = 0;

        do {
            numberChecker = numberChecker && Character.isDigit(isbn.charAt(s));
            s++;
        } while (s < isbn.length() || numberChecker == false);
    } while (isbn.length() != 12 & numberChecker == false);

    int sum = 0;
    int s = 0;
    do {
        if (s % 2 == 0) {
            sum = sum + isbn.charAt(s) - 48;
        } else {
            sum = sum + 3 * (isbn.charAt(s) - 48);
        }
        s++;
    } while (s < 12);
    {
        sum = 10 - (sum % 10);
        if (sum == 10)
            sum = 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Your ISBN is " + isbn + sum);
}

private static boolean doThisAgain(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String doOver = sc.nextLine();
    return doOver.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to " + TITLE);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        process(sc, args);
    } while (doThisAgain(sc, CONTINUE_PROMPT));
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the " + TITLE);

}
```

It should display "Do this again? [y/n]" with you inputting "y" to start the process over and entering "n" to stop and have the system print out ("Thank you for using the " + TITLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have closed the scanner instance already using line **input.close();**

Just comment out or delete **input.close();** and your program will work as expected.

```
        System.out.println("\nEnter the first 12 digits of an ISBN-13: ");
        isbn = input.nextLine();
       //input.close();
```

Let me know if it helps! :)

Comment: It's perfect now thank you! Now just to have figure out where to put the system.out.println("invalid input") and I'm golden : )

Comment: Glad it hepled :) Good luck